# Compilation error when decimal is entered in Java code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm a complete beginner and trying to write a code to print the factorial of a number. I want the user to be able to enter any possible number they want, but if they enter a number that is not a positive integer, the program tells them they have to try again. But when I run the code and try entering '5.5', I get a compilation error. I cannot figure out why. What is going wrong?

```
package javaExercises;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fac {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            double result = 1; //initialize our result variable 

            System.out.println("Enter a positive  integer: ");
            double fac = in.nextDouble();

            if (fac != (int) fac)
                System.out.println("Your entry is not an integer.");
            else if (fac < 0)
                System.out.println("Your entry is negative.");
            else if (fac == 0)
                System.out.println("The factorial of 0 is 1.");
            else {
                for (double i = fac; i > 1; i--)
                    result *= i;

                System.out.println("The factorial of " + Math.round(fac) + " is " + Math.round(result) + ".");
            }

        } finally {
            in .close();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
Enter a positive integer: 4.5 Exception in thread "main"
java.util.InputMismatchException at 
java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939) at 
java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594) at 
java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564) at 
javaExercises.Fac.main(Fac.java:16) –
```

Comment: You get a runtime error, the program is already compiled.

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: `run the code and try entering '5.5', I get a compilation error` error encountered in running state is not a compilation error

Comment: *"But when I run the code and try entering '5.5', I get a compilation error."* If you're running the code, it's not a compilation error. Compilation errors occur during compilation, which is *before* you run the code. If it's happening when running the code, it's a *runtime* error. Either way, when asking about an error, it's important to copy and paste the error to the question.

Comment: the error is 

Enter a positive  integer: 
4.5
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
 at javaExercises.Fac.main(Fac.java:16)

Comment: Please add the exception as part of question and not as comment

Comment: Are you in a location which uses comma `,` as a decimal point?

Comment: Are you sure you're not writing `5,5` with a comma?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes this could possibly be the reason of exception +1

Comment: Here's what you need, [nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble())

Comment: @soufrk - Notice the use of Scanner.

Comment: Just a side note, "Enter a positive  integer" is an odd way to prompt for a possibly-fractional number.

Comment: Yes, it was the comma! I didn't know I needed a comma instead of a decimal ,thank you all!

Comment: okay, well now it works when I type '5,5' but it doesn't work when I type '5.5' so I am very confused now.

Comment: @jgcello - Ignore my (deleted) comment about `nextDouble`, it says it uses the locale-sensitive decimal separator, which is apparently `,` in your locale: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--

Comment: Don't forget to add the exception trace to the actual question, as @soufrk mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

It´s the behaviour of the `default-location` of your PC or more detailed the used numeric formatters for your location set on the JVM. Date does the same btw.

So for example I´m german and got this setting on my PC. Now I need to enter digits like this: `5,5` because `,` is the default separator in germany. Same happens witch date/... so 23. Nov will be 23/11 and not 11/23 like in US.

you can change default input types using this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US); // 5.5, DE=5,5, ....
```

---

It´s not a compilation error because the programm can be compiled and started. The error is triggerd while running so it´s a runtime-error.